# Problema con columna en bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Buenas, tengo este problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo quiero es que la ultima columna ocupe todo el alto(height) de la pagina sin afectar a las otras columnas que como se ve en la imagen empiezan abajo.

```html
<div class="container" id="wrapnoti">
        
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div style="background:url(https://media.easports.com/content/www-easports/es_ES/fifa/noticias/2015/fifa-16-gameplay-improvements/_jcr_content/headerImages/image.img.jpg);background-size:150%" class="noticia">
              <div class="contitulo">
              <p id="titulo">Probamos el FIFA 17</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div style="background:url(http://nivelxtremo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/11.jpg);background-size:150%" class="noticia">
              <div class="contitulo">
              <p id="titulo">La decepcion de Agustin Pantano</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/aafifaok" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/aafifaok" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/aafifaok">Asociación Argentina de FIFA - AAFIFA</a></blockquote></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div style="background:url(http://img.fifa.com/mm/photo/tournament/competition/02/60/69/19/2606919_full-lnd.jpg);background-size:150%" class="noticia">
              <div class="contitulo">
              <p id="titulo">Abdulaziz Alshehri de Arabia Saudita se consagro campeon</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

Saludos!

Comment: ya intentaste colocanco col-md-12 claro pensando que es tipo medium

Comment: subir el codigo por favor

Comment: quiero que lo ocupe verticalmente :p

Comment: ahi subi el codigo!, gracias

Comment: la neta no te entiendo, explicate mejor

Comment: ahi esta la foto daniel, quiero que la ultima columna (la de facebook) ocupe todo el ALTO de la pagina, y ves que la columna de la segunda fila comienza debajo de la columna de facebook? no quiero que pase eso, quiero que este debajo de las otras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separa en 2 div el primero ponle `col-md-10` y el segundo `col-md-2` quedaria de esta forma

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container col-md-10" id="wrapnoti">
        
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div style="background:url(https://media.easports.com/content/www-easports/es_ES/fifa/noticias/2015/fifa-16-gameplay-improvements/_jcr_content/headerImages/image.img.jpg);background-size:150%" class="noticia">
              <div class="contitulo">
              <p id="titulo">Probamos el FIFA 17</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div style="background:url(http://nivelxtremo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/11.jpg);background-size:150%" class="noticia">
              <div class="contitulo">
              <p id="titulo">La decepcion de Agustin Pantano</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>        

        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div style="background:url(http://img.fifa.com/mm/photo/tournament/competition/02/60/69/19/2606919_full-lnd.jpg);background-size:150%" class="noticia">
              <div class="contitulo">
              <p id="titulo">Abdulaziz Alshehri de Arabia Saudita se consagro campeon</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div>
          <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/aafifaok" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/aafifaok" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/aafifaok">Asociación Argentina de FIFA - AAFIFA</a></blockquote></div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: crack!, exactamente asi era, me solucionaste muchisimos problemas, gracias!